# PhotoSwipe and Masonry Navigation Arrows Missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a portfolio website using both Masonry and PhotoSwipe. The navigation arrows do not  show and gallery is not navigable via gestures. 
Can PhotoSwipe be used with Masonry?

Here's a bit of my code:

```
<div class="main-container">
<div class="main clear fix">
<div id="content">
<!-- Portfolio Rendering -->
<div class="grid">          
div class="grid-sizer">
<div class="grid-item">
<a href="portfolio/01.jpg" data-size="900x1200" data-med="portfolio/600/01.jpg" data-med-size="600x800" data-author="">
<img src="portfolio/600/01.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
</div>
<div class="grid-item">
<a href="portfolio/02.jpg" data-size="900x1200" data-med="portfolio/600/02.jpg" data-med-size="600x900" data-author=""><img src="portfolio/600/02.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
</div>
<div class="grid-item"><a href="portfolio/03.jpg" data-size="900x1200" data-med="portfolio/600/03.jpg" data-med-size="600x800" data-author="">            <img src="portfolio/600/03.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
</div></div></div>
</div></div></div>

<div class="pswp" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="pswp__bg"></div>
<div class="pswp__scroll-wrap">
<div class="pswp__container">
<div class="pswp__item"></div>
<div class="pswp__item"></div>
<div class="pswp__item"></div>
</div>
<div class="pswp__ui pswp__ui--hidden">
<div class="pswp__top-bar">
<button class="pswp__button pswp__button--close" title="Close (Esc)"></button>                  <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--zoom" title="Zoom in/out"></button>                                           <div class="pswp__preloader">
<div class="pswp__preloader__icn">
<div class="pswp__preloader__cut">
<div class="pswp__preloader__donut"></div>
</div></div></div></div>
<!-- <div class="pswp__loading-indicator">
<div class="pswp__loading-indicator__line">
</div></div> -->
<button class="pswp__button pswp__button--arrow--right" title="Next (arrow right)"></button>
<button class="pswp__button pswp__button--arrow--left" title="Previous (arrow left)"></button>
</div></div></div>
```

Comment: I found that the problem is with using DIVs to separate images to allow for flex box/masonry layout. If I combine all images in a group, then the arrows appear fine, but I loose the Masonry functionality. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's a bit late, but I was searching for a fix with no luck, until eventually I figured it out. My HTML, though, was a bit different, based on the suggestion on the [official documentation](http://photoswipe.com/documentation/getting-started.html) of PhotoSwipe:

```
 <div class="my-gallery" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">
    <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
    <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
        <a href="large-image.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="600x400">
            <img src="small-image.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
        </a>
    </figure>

    <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
        <a href="large-image.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="600x400">
            <img src="small-image.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
        </a>
    </figure>
</div>
```

When I wrapped the `<figure>` tag in a `div`, masonry was working, but PhotoSwipe navigation didn't. If I removed the `div`, PhotoSwipe navigation was OK but the layout got messed up. Eventually, I removed the .grid-sizer div and, instead, added the class .grid-sizer on the first  element of the gallery, which fixed the issue. So, the working markup in my case was something like that (notice the extra class on the first `<figure>` element):

```
 <div class="my-gallery" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">
    <figure class="grid-sizer" itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
        <a href="large-image.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="600x400">
            <img src="small-image.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
        </a>
    </figure>

    <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
        <a href="large-image.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="600x400">
            <img src="small-image.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
        </a>
    </figure>
</div>
```

That way, Masonry used the first item to calculate the responsive layout and PhotoSwipe was happy with the markup.